# How to get a file to be used as input of the program that ends with special character in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have an output file from a code which its name will ends to "_x.txt" and I want to connect two codes which second code will use this file as an input and will add more data into it. Finally, it will ends into "blabla_x_f.txt"
I am trying to work it out as below, but seems it is not correct and  I could not solve it. Please help:

```
 inf = str(raw_input(*+"_x.txt"))
 with open(inf+'_x.txt') as fin, open(inf+'_x_f.txt','w') as fout:
 ....(other operations)
```

The main problem is that the "blabla" part of the file could change to any thing every time and will be random strings, so the code needs to be flexible and just search for whatever ends with "_x.txt".

Comment: Please clarify your problem.

Comment: I need to get the file which has random name in the beginning but ends with "_x.txt" and use it in the next code as input file. I will add your solution in the second code to get the file and do operation on it and finally give me "blabla_x_f.txt". Is it clear now? @Thomas Erker

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Python's `glob` module:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('*_x.txt')
```

gives you a list of all files ending in `_x.txt`. Continue with

```
for path in files:
    newpath = path[:-4] + '_f.txt' 
    with open(path) as in:
        with open(newpath, 'w') as out:
            # do something
```

Comment: This is good just to find the file, but I need to open it and use data inside it as input file, That was the main problem.Could you please help me with that?!